# Spring Boot - manual JPA configuration with profiles problem

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I've got a problem with my Spring Boot app JPA configuration. I've got two profiles - dev (H2 db) and prod (PostgreSQL). I want to manually set up JPA without Spring Boot "magic", so I've created configuration class shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext {

@Primary
@Bean
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return properties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource(dataSourceProperties()));
    em.setPackagesToScan("model");
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}

}
```

The problem occurs when I want to test saving to database in the dev profile. When I'm performing test I've got this error :

```
10:37:47.951 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Book (id, author, bookType, bookstore, new_price, old_price, title, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
10:37:47.955 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not prepare statement [insert into Book (id, author, bookType, bookstore, new_price, old_price, title, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BOOK" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Book (id, author, bookType, bookstore, new_price, old_price, title, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-197]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
```

My application-dev.properties file looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

I figured out that it might be a problem with `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`, cause when I set this property via property map inside PersistenceContext class it's working properly. I don't know how to set it correctly via a properties file. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't use Spring Boot so setting the properties through `application.properties` doesn't work either. Why don't you want to use spring boot and goto lengths avoiding it?

Comment: I just wanted to get better knowledge about JPA and how it works without magic provided by Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` does the same thing. But since you are opted not using Spring Autoconfiguration Magic these properties are ineffective.

So you have to use JPA Property Map and set it in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.